# How to abort file upload in apollo-upload-client?

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

I was looking into the code of `apollo-upload-client` and i came across the following code -

```
var _createSignalIfSuppor = createSignalIfSupported(),
        controller = _createSignalIfSuppor.controller,
        signal = _createSignalIfSuppor.signal

if (controller) options.signal = signal
```

It seems to override the `signal` object passed with query/mutation's `fetchOption` and replace with another `signal` object.

Given this, can anyone please tell me how should i abort the file upload as i dont have access to this `AbortController` object.